# Java 2D game rectangle collision resonce

Tags: java, if-statement, collision-detection

I have been working on a very simple 2D game, it is very basic, it has a Play class with methods such as init, render and update inside of it, I have made a 2D map and a player that moved around when there is a keyboard input, this is done very simply using just If statements. The game kind of has a pokemon view (overhead view) you can move up, down, left and right. On my map there is a obstacle and at the moment when I play the game the player just walks through the obstacle, I want the player to stop when he reaches the obstacle and not be able to walk through it so I researched collision detection and managed to make a start, in my code I have made 2 rectangles:

```
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(buckyPositionX, buckyPositionY, 40, 40);
Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(-100, -143, 70,70);
```

and have also made a boolean for the variable x which returns true if the two rectangles intersect:

```
boolean x = rectOne.intersects(rectTwo);
```

After doing this I am now confused on exactly how to say to java, if boolean returns true stop the player from going through that rectangle, I know it is a if statement searching if x returns true but I dont know what to put inside of it and I am hoping some of the more experienced users can help be solve this problem.

Comment: Given that slew of words contains no '?' according to FF 'find', prompts me to ask..  Do you have a question, & if so, what is it? v As an aside, if 'Ben Dover' is your real name, I suggest you change your ID to 'Benjamin Dover', if not, I suggest you 'grow up' & stop using characters in tired jokes as an ID.

Comment: My name is actually Ben but my friend at the time I was making my account actually set my last name to Dover, I have used this yahoo account for a long time and the full name only appears when I enter this forum, I am sorry about that.

Comment: About the multiple questions, I am new to Java and my first question started off very vague as I did not have any idea what I was doing, this lead to further confusion when people did not understand exactly what I was asking and the thread started going off topic, I slowly got to learn that I can use different types of collisions and eventually got to the point where I know the basics about the Rectangle collision, as I learnt more about Java I thought making a new question may be better than working with the old ones where things were going off topic.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to write a method `changeBuckyPos` that checks for collisions and updates `buckyPositionX` and `buckyPositionY` if there is no collision.

```
public void changeBuckyPos(float deltaX, float deltaY) {
  float newX = buckyPositionX + deltaX;
  float newY = buckyPositionY + deltaY;

  // check for collisions
  Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle((int)newX, (int)newY, 40, 40);
  Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(-100, -143, 70,70);

  if (!rectOne.intersects(rectTwo)) {
    buckyPositionX = newX;        
    buckyPositionY = newY;        
  }
}
```

This could also be used for all the key event handlers that are in the current code to make it more clear, something like this:

```
public void changeBuckyPos(float deltaX, float deltaY) {
  float newX = buckyPositionX + deltaX;
  float newY = buckyPositionY + deltaY;

  // check for collisions
  Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle((int)newX, (int)newY, 40, 40);
  Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(-100, -143, 70,70);

  if (!rectOne.intersects(rectTwo)) {
    // check global limits
    if ((newX > -1000) && (newX < 1000) && (newY > -1000) && (newY < 1000)) {
      buckyPositionX = newX;
      buckyPositionY = newY;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, I am using the first code you posted at the moment as it seems simpler, I placed it after my update method and changed mu buckyPositionX and Y to floats, that cleared most of the errors but I am now getting 2 more errors, under rectOne it is saying the constructor Rectangle (float,float,int,int) is undefined and the next error is the changeBuckyPos, it says void is a invalid type for the value changeBuckyPos. Could you please help me fix these errors? Thank you.

Comment: Edited the code to fix fhe Rectangle error - the variables have to be cast to `int`.

Comment: Thank you, it has fixed all of the errors now but I am having problems with the collision, when I go to the coordinates on my game nothing happens, I mean I thought the code would stop the player from going through the house on my map at them coordinates.